# Is there a way how to authenticate into Dynamics CRM API without username/password

Tags: authentication, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a website which needs to contact Dynamics CRM (online 2015) through its API. The web server is not part of company domain. From the documentation it seems the only way how to do it, is use user's login credentials. I'm feeling uneasy to have CRM administrator's credentials stored somewhere in 'plaintext'.

Is there a way how to authenticate with some pre-generated API key/token? What is the best practice for using the credentials? Should I create special user account (assign CRM license), possibly with limited rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the only authentication is username/password.  You should never have any credentials stored in 'plain text'.  At the very least do a basic encryption on your password and decrypt it in your code.

I definitely recommend creating a specialised account for integration and restricting its rights as much as possible (especially using CRM Online!).  Then you can at least ensure they can't create new users etc.